# I can load functions from dynamic library with linking this dl ,but I can not load it using 'dlsym' in the code without linking this dl

Tags: c++, c, linux, compiler-construction, linker

I am using gcc/g++ on fedora 116, and my idea is:

```
c program -> load c++ dynamic library A -> load c++ dynamic library B
```

The c++ dynamic library B is third-party provided and I can not modify it.

When complinng c++ dynamic library A with linking c++ dynamic library B, A can find symbols in B. But when I load B functions in A code (not linking) using 'dlsym', A tells me

```
/path/to/B.so: undefined symbol: some_func
```

=============================

use nm -DC

```
0000000000014a80 T BinarySearch(int, int*, int)
0000000000007210 T CheckLicense()
0000000000009370 T GetEnd(stCha*, int&, int)
000000000000a970 T IC_Exit()
000000000000a740 T IC_Init(char const*)
```

the error report:

```
/path/to/some.so undefined symbol: IC_Init
```

the code in library A:

```
IC_API bool (* IC_Init)(const char *);
IC_Init = (IC_API bool (*)(const char *)) dlsym(dl_ic, "IC_Init");
if(IC_Init) {
    printf("function loaded");
}
```

in library A, it can load library B using dlopen:

```
void *dl_ic = dlopen(ic_lib_path, RTLD_LAZY);
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the code that A is using that includes `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` to link to the function in B?

Comment: When building `libA.so`, do you link-in `libB.so` ? Do you use `-rdynamic` to link your entire executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered name mangling?  C++ identifiers are typically "mangled" to incorporate information on their namespace and arguments (which historically helped linkers differentiate overloaded functions).  You may want to make the function `extern "C"` to prevent mangling, or find its mangled name to use with `dlsym` (e.g. on Linx use `nm` on an object, or `gcc -S -o /dev/tty ... | grep some_func` on the source).

Comment: what you mean "find its mangled name to use with dlsym"? Do you mean I have to use another name in 'dlsym' rather than the originally defined name? I have updated my question, please help check, thanks

Comment: or just take off the `-C` switch in the `nm` command the OP already posted, which will turn off the symbol-unmangling

Comment: @Mickey: as araqnid pointed out, you're using the -C switch with nm, so that you get the readable function signatures you've used in your source code.  Behind the scenes, the C++ compiler actually converts those to a tangle of underscores and alphanumerics, encoding the namespaces and/or class/struct scope the function appears as well as the argument types and member-function constness.  That is the "real" symbolic name in the objects symbol table - the name you need to provide to dlsym.  If you have `extern "C" IC_API bool IC_Init(const char *)`, the compiler won't mangle it.

Comment: To be more concrete: if I use g++ to compile a function `bool IC_Init(const char*)`, then use nm on the object to see the mangled name, it's actually `__Z7IC_InitPKc`.  This is probably the name you need to ask dlsym to find, but you should check whether your compiler version has encoded it a little differently.  You'll get more robust, version-independent code by using `extern "C"` to disable mangling.