# g++ undefined reference although symbol is present in *.so file

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference, name-mangling

I found a number of similar questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849422/undefined-reference-to-symbol-even-when-nm-indicates-that-this-symbol-is-present), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456581/undefined-reference-to-symbol-even-when-nm-indicates-that-this-symbol-is-present) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526688/i-can-load-functions-from-dynamic-library-with-linking-this-dl-but-i-can-not-lo)), but none of them helped me solve my problem. I have a *.so file (from the core of [gnss-sdr](http://gnss-sdr.org/)) that, as indicated by:

```
$nm libgnss_system_parameters_dyn.so  | c++filt  |grep Gps_Eph
```

contains the symbol `Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephemeris()`, which is supposed to be a constructor.

I've written some minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <core/system_parameters/gps_ephemeris.h>

int main(int argc,const char* argv[])
{
    Gps_Ephemeris ge;
    return 0; 
}
```

which I compile with:

```
g++  main.cpp -std=c++0x -I some_include_path -L some_lib_path -l gnss_system_parameters_dyn`
```

The linker then complains:

```
/tmp/ccHCvldG.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephemeris()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried *cmake*, but the line it generated was similar to that (it just added `-rdynamic` before linking), and it still generated the exact same linker error.

Note that both the library and my minimal code are being compiled with the same compiler (g++-5), with the exact same flags and the same c++0x standard.

---

Addressing the answer by Maxim Egorushkin, the line:

```
nm --demangle --defined-only --extern-only libgnss_system_parameters.so  |grep Gps_Eph
```

doesn't output anything. However, the symbol is defined in the static library (*i.e.* the *.a library):

```
00000000000006b0 T Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephemeris()
00000000000006b0 T Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephemeris()
```

Knowing that both are generated by *cmake*, in the following way:

```
add_library(lib_name SHARED ${sources_etc}) #for the *.so
add_library(lib_name_2 ${sources_etc}) #for the *.a
```

there should be no difference in symbols contained/defined in those libraries, right? I didn't notice anything in *cmake*'s documentation on `add_library`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You said the output _contains the symbol `Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephermeris()`_, but don't show the actual output. This is relevant, and would be useful. Also, you clearly haven't copied-and-pasted that symbol into the question, because you misspelt it. I'm mistrustful of written summaries of this kind, because if you were a reliable judge of what to exclude from your summary, you probably wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I fixed it. I mostly do high-level computer vision, so yes, I feel unqualified to judge what has to be excluded. I will post the output as soon as I can.

Comment: Without looking at the source code it is hard to tell why the .so and .a built from the same sources export different symbols. Conditional compilation may be involved.

Comment: What are the mangled symbol names in both main.o and in libgnss_system_parameters_dyn.so? G++ has changed name mangling on occasion when the ABI has changed. Perhaps libgnss_system_parameters_dyn.so was not compiled the same as how you're compiling main.cpp. Try `g++ -std=c++0x -c main.cpp; nm main.o` and compare the mangled names to what's in the lib.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The pedantically correct way to check that a `.so` exports a symbol is `nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only <lib.so> | grep <symbol>`.

Without `--defined-only` your command also shows *undefined* symbols.

Without `--extern-only` it also shows symbols with *internal linkage* which are unavailable for linking.

It looks like you need to link another library because `Gps_Ephemeris::Gps_Ephermeris()` is not resolved by linking `libgnss_system_parameters_dyn.so`. A good way to start is that library's documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were right. However, the symbols are present in the (equivalent) static library. I updated the question with some information at the end. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 6):

I have found in the past that this type of error is caused by the lack of proper `extern "C" { ... }` bracketing in an include file.

Comment: Could you elaborate how `extern "C"` linkage handles constructors?

Comment: It doesn't. They are not part of C, but of C++.